# Setting request attribute to null on resubmitting same request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have this scenario:

I need to upload an attachment to a server. I have a `jsp page` and a `servlet` which processes my requests. Before I upload the file, I need to check for duplicate filenames so that I don't replace the file without informing the user. So in my servlet I am doing the appropriate check and setting a `request attribute` to true so that when I `forward the request to the jsp page` and see that the attribute is set to true, I display a dialog to the user (with the use of jquery) so that the user chooses which action to be taken (Keep Both, Overwrite, Cancel).

The only concern I have is that when the page is refreshed i.e. the `same request is submitted`, after the attribute was set to true, the `attribute remains true` and therefore on refresh I am getting my dialog on load. Of course, I don't want this to happen.

Is there something which can help me go around this? This is the code I have.

**UploadFile.java** - My Servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, java.io.IOException
{
     request.setAttribute("duplicate", null);

     if (!isDuplicate(file)){
        // .. handle uploading 
     } 
     else 
     {
        // if duplicate
        request.setAttribute("duplicate", "true");

        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/ticketsform.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
     }

     response.sendRedirect("ticketform.jsp");
}
```

**ticketform.jsp**

```
<% 
    String isDuplicate = (String)request.getAttribute("duplicate"); 

    if (isDuplicate != null)
    {   %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            duplicateFilesOption(); // call js function to display dialog
        </script>
<%  }   %>
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: the isDuplicate is returning good results. true when duplicate, false when not. on page refresh, it remains true if the last request was a duplicate file.

Comment: you can put isDuplicate to some hidden field that can dynamiclly change by javascript/jquery.

Comment: Set caching headers (see melt321) but I would Ajax post of the filename to the servlet for validation before the full post should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your jsp.

This will tell the browser to re-send the request rather than redisplay the results.

```
<head>   
<meta HTTP-EQUIV=Expires CONTENT="0">   
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">  
<head>
```

Comment: tried this and didn't do any difference. thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

At end of ticketform.jsp please remove the attribute.

```
request.removeAttribute("attribute_name");
```

So after getting value from request at first it will remove every time at last.

Comment: tried it but didn't work either! Still getting the dialog on refresh load

Comment: Ok i think the url at the time you refreshing will cause action to servlet and setting request attribute again. Please check the url of the page after and before submitting the action. It's better to use response.sendRedirect() method in servlet after operation with putting flag in HttpSession and get value from session at first of jsp page then remove the session value at last.

Comment: I think the fact that it is not going to the servlet again is affecting this since if it is resubmitting, there's the set attribute null statement. Do you think that if I use ajax instead of redirections, this will be solved?